# Only First Item is Added to Array

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I have a for loop that goes through an array of tweets I get from the Twitter API. As long as the coordinates for each tweet are not null, an annotation is created with the screen_name from the tweet as the title and the coordinates of the tweet. Each annotation is added to an array and when the loop is finished, the annotations from that array are added to a map view. My issue is that only the first tweet is getting added as an annotation. What am I missing?

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"key" consumerSecret:@"secret"];

    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:@"apple" geocode:geoCode lang:nil locale:nil resultType:@"recent" count:@"10" until:nil sinceID:nil maxID:nil includeEntities:nil callback:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {

            tweetsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];
            NSLog(@"tweetsArray: %@", tweetsArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < [tweetsArray count]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *t = tweetsArray[i];
                tweetAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

                NSArray *tweetLocation = [[t valueForKey:@"geo"]valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
                NSLog(@"Tweet Location: %@", tweetLocation);

                if ([tweetLocation isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    double lat = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
                    double longitude = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
                    locationCoord.latitude = lat;
                    locationCoord.longitude = longitude;
                    NSLog(@"Lat: %.8f, Long: %.8f", lat, longitude);

                    twitterName = [t valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"];
                    NSLog(@"Twitter name: %@", twitterName);
                    tweetAnnotation.title = twitterName;

                    tweetAnnotation.coordinate = locationCoord;
                    [tweetLocationsArray addObject:tweetAnnotation];
                }
            }

            [tweetMap addAnnotations:tweetLocationsArray];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

        }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

    }];
```

Comment: Have you debugged this in any way? Put a breakpoint where you add the item to your array, then find out why it only gets called one time and so on

Comment: Check if your NSArray *statuses hold more than 1 object and than if your tweetsArray get all that objects.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue where I'm adding annotations from an NSMutableArray and only the first one gets added.